# how to clear memory of global variables?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using global variables to save big dataframe which is read from a file, so when it is read the first time executing callback, it is saved at a global variable. so when calling next time callback, I don't need to read it from an extenal file again, I just use it from global variable. Overtime, the dash app becomes very laggy due to big data saved in global variables. so my question is how to clear the memory of global variables so the dash app is not laggy?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that's what's making the app laggy and not something else?

Comment: yes I am sure. befor using that, my app is running fine.

Comment: Assuming the dataframe is the problem I'd start thinking about if you need all the data you're reading in or if you only need a part. Do you need all rows, all columns? Etc... Another option is to use something like a dask dataframe. It can read a csv, but will not load data into memory immediately. It will lazy load, load only when you need it. Might be interesting to look into.

Comment: You can just do `del some_var` to free up the memory held by `some_var`

Comment: @pavi2410 I don't think that's really an option. OP has defined the global variable in order to be able to refer to it in callbacks. When do you decide you don't need it anymore in this situation?